# SQL Update Statement for change to correct fractions

Tags: html, sql, regex

In my database, I have strings saved like this:

```
<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>
```

This basically stores the fraction as html, but I want to change the html statement to this:

```
<div class="fraction">
  <div class="numerator">3</div>
  <div class="denominator">8</div>
</div>
```

I know how to change it using SQL UPDATE Statement:

```
UPDATE question_table 
SET `option` = Replace(`option`, '<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>','<div class="fraction">
      <div class="numerator">3</div>
      <div class="denominator">8</div>
    </div>')
WHERE `option` LIKE  '%<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>%'
```

But the problem is the 3 and 8 might change accordingly. It is not always 3 and 8. The numbers can change. How do I change it to the correct statement taking into account the different numbers. I know I need to use regular expressions but not sure how.

Need guidance on this.

Comment: And this is exactly why storing precomposed string values in a database is ugly at best. This is almost as bad as the comma-separated-list-in-a-single-column. If you had two columns "numerator" and "denominator" you would already be done, and as a bonus you would be able to calculate the decimal value and even sort by it if you wanted.

Comment: Not to mention of course I'd put $5 down to say you're just dumping this HTML code on an output page raw, without any type of sanitation. If anyone ever got into your database, it would be *so* easy to inject malware.

Comment: how can they inject malware so easily? what do u mean without any type of sanitation?

Comment: This problem shouldn't exist in the first place. Keep only data in your database, leave the formatting and presentation for the presentation layer.

Comment: Gee, let me see... `update question_table set option = '<a href="http://myevilsite.com">click here</a>'` would be a quick and easy start.

Comment: you could use a placeholder to replace 3 and 8 with values you want, like #PH1 and #PH2 and later do a replace("#PH1",3) on the string with this value. But anyway, lc is right, storing HTML in database is dangerous...

Comment: I understand @lc point. But now I want to look at all the rows and change the options such that replace the string such that I replace the string properly. How do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

All of the comment above are wise and valid. However, if you really need to keep it the way it is, you can try something like that:

```
declare @t table ([id] int, [fraction]  nvarchar(max));
insert into @t([id], [fraction]) values(0, '<sup>3</sup>&frasl;<sub>8</sub>');

; with n as (
select [id], [numerator] = substring([fraction], CHARINDEX('<sup>', [fraction], 0) + len('<sup>'), CHARINDEX('</sup>', [fraction], 0) - CHARINDEX('<sup>', [fraction], 0) - len('<sup>'))
    , [denominator] = substring([fraction], CHARINDEX('<sub>', [fraction], 0) + len('<sub>'), CHARINDEX('</sub>', [fraction], 0) - CHARINDEX('<sub>', [fraction], 0) - len('<sub>'))
From @t
)
Select [id], [html] = '<div class="fraction"><div class="numerator">'+n.[numerator]+'</div><div class="denominator">'+n.[denominator]+'</div>div>'
From n;
```

This code works as it is in SMSS with SQL Server. Replace and adapt it to your model and needs and to your RDBMS.
Julien